# Api root con Django funciona bien pero se muestra mal visualmente

Tags: django, api

Es un error que no afecta para nada al funcionamiento pero no se porque se muestra mal visualmente

[image: La api-root Se muestra mal visualmente]

Answer (score 0):

Hola tiene toda la pinta que te esta fallando la ruta de acceso a los archivos estáticos de tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos.